# Is it acceptable to encapsulate each js file with an IIFE?

Tags: javascript, syntax, encapsulation

Is it acceptable to encapsulate each js file with an IIFE?

For example, in file somefile.js instead of:

```
var x = ...
var y = ...
function foo() {...}
...
```

to make:

```
(function() {
var x = ...
var y = ...
function foo() {...}
...
}());
```

And do the same with all of the js files. This will hide the functions and global variables from the users so they won't be able to easily invoke or change them.

Comment: Unless you don't need to share global variables between files, it's fine.

Comment: Sure, is there any reason you think it's not?..  Of course if you want your JS files to talk to each other then it won't work.. But in that case I would suggest a module loader..

Comment: This is actually a good practice, this ensures that any of your variables wont clash with any other global variables. Since JS doesnt have a linker, all the js files are thrown into the global scope, so its good practice encapsulate using IFFEs

Comment: @Keith I just want to make sure. I see that a module loader is a third party library, it doesn't come in chrome?

Comment: Currently browsers don't implement loaders, but in the future they will.  And in the mean time there is a `system.js` to act as a polyfill. https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs  You can also use bundlers like webpack or browserfy..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it acceptable to encapsulate each js file with an IIFE?

Yes, totally acceptable.

However it might not be too useful, because you usually want some functions from a js file to be invokable from elsewhere.

> This will hide the functions and global variables from the users so they won't be able to easily invoke or change them.

No, hiding anything from the users is futile.

The purpose of IIFEs is to hide the file's local variables from each other, i.e. to separate the js modules.